# My blender is too slow to work

Tags: performance

[image]I'm using Blender3.0.0
It's getting too slow to even just open a file.
I've been using Blender for editing 3D scanned objects and these objects have many vertices, I think that's why? because, until importing around 10 objects (in different saves)it was running normally.

How can I fix that?

I'm using Mac

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you kindly tell how many vertices/faces? Since currently it's hard to tell what's the problem.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry thank you for responding I updated the image

Comment: It doesn't look like the scene is very heavy (for my device) but as your screenshot shows, you're averaging 7.1 GB of memory out of 8. That leaves very little memory for any other process, and of course, will lag in Blender. The more powerful your computer, the faster blender will be. And you've just selected one object. Imagine the load on your memory the three objects will be putting altogether, no wonder it's slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to only edit one mesh per file, given the performance limitations of your hardware.

Remember that it's always going to be more performant to modify a mesh in Sculpt mode than in Edit mode.

400k-vert model in Sculpt mode:

[image]

Same Mesh in Edit mode:

[image]

You could also try to remesh your model then subdivide it with a Multiresolution modifier and Shrinkwrap it to your original mesh to retain the detail.

Multiresolution will adaptively display a lower res version of your model whenever you move around in the viewport (in sculpt mode only), to improve performance.
[image]

You can also set the viewport subdivisions to be lower elsewhere.

[image]

Then if you absolutely have to you can add this object to a collection, then link that collection to a master blend file if you have to render/ work with them in the same blend file.

[image]

Linked Hi Res Monkey Collection from other blend file.

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what the performance implications of this method are, vs just appending the object to the scene, I imagine it's the best case scenario though.